# Deploy Dacpac packages via power shell script to Azure SQL Server

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dacpac

I'm trying to deploy multiple dacpac's during single build process by using PowerShell script.

```
param(
    [string]$publish_profile,
    [string]$path_to_snapshots,
    [string]$password 
)

#Load Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac")

#Load Dac profile 
$dacProfile = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile]::Load($publish_profile)
$dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($dacProfile.TargetConnectionString)

$files = Get-ChildItem  "$path_to_snapshots\*.dacpac"
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $fileName = $file.Name 
    Try
    {
            $dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($file.FullName)
            $dacService.Deploy($dp, $database, $true) 
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "$fileName deployment has been failed"  -foregroundcolor "red"
        throw $_.Exception;
        Break
    }
}
```

On my local environment everything works great, but during build process on the Visual Studio team services I get an error:

> 2017-02-24T06:03:09.7955300Z *********.dacpac deployment has been failed
>   2017-02-24T06:03:09.9785258Z ##[error]Exception calling "Deploy" with "3" argument(s): "Could not deploy package."
>   At D:\a\1\s********************\deploydatabase.ps1:104 char:13
>   +             $dacService.Deploy($dp, $database, $true)
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DacServicesException
>
> 2017-02-24T06:03:10.0085256Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent?

Comment: yes, I'm using the hosting agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add firewall rule in order to connect to Azure SQL Server.

1. Edit your build definition
2. Select Option tab and check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token
3. Add Azure PowerShell step (arguments: -RestAddress https://[account].vsdtl.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/vslabs/ipaddress -Token $(System.AccessToken) -RG [resource group] -Server [server name] -ruleName $(Build.BuildNumber)

Code:

```
param (
    [string]$RestAddress,
    [string]$Token,
    [string]$RG,
    [string]$Server
    )
$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f 'test',$Token)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth)}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RestAddress -headers $headers -Method Get
Write-Host $result.value
New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $RG -ServerName $Server -FirewallRuleName "UnitTestRule" -StartIpAddress "$($result.value)" -EndIpAddress "$($result.value)"
```

Secondly, I recommend you use the assembly in this package: 
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac/).

Thirdly, to get the detail error, you can use this code instead:

```
Catch
    {
        Write-Host "$fileName deployment has been failed"  -foregroundcolor "red"
         $Error | format-list -force
        Write-Host $Error[0].Exception.ParentContainsErrorRecordException;
        Break
    }
```

On the other hand, I recommend you can deploy SQL package through [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I added new powershell task and did as you described the firewall was added to my server. 
 Also I get detail exception message:
  Exception calling "Deploy" with "5" argument(s): "Could not deploy package." 
  The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. 
  You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database 
 platform service.

Comment: @TimurAbdurafeev Do you use the assembly files in this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac/?

Comment: @TimurAbdurafeev I am using 1.0.3 and it is working fine. (I put them in lib folder) and the code to load assembly: $psPath=$PSScriptRoot  Add-Type -Path "$psPath\lib\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"

Comment: Thanks, now everything works as expected
P.S.  $psPath=Add-Type -Path "$psPath\lib\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll
instead of  $psPath=$PSScriptRoot Add-Type -Path "$psPath\lib\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll