# How to execute a cmd file in VSTS CD pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I created a cmd file that basically executes all sql scripts sequentially. I am using a windows private build agent in VSTS. How do I execute this .cmd file? Is there any other task that executes multiple sql scripts against an Azure SQL database? Any suggestions will help. Below is the contents of cmd file:

@Echo Off 
FOR /f %%i IN ('DIR *.Sql /B') do call :RunScript %%i 
GOTO :END

:RunScript 
Echo Executing Script: %1 
sqlcmd -S <> -U <> -P <> -d PFUTest -i %1  -o log.txt
Echo Completed Script: %1

:END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding execute sql scripts against an Azure SQL database, you can use [Azure SQL Database Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeployment) task (Select SQL Script file or Inline SQL Script in Type input box of Deployment Package section.

With batch script, you can call [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) command to run SQL scripts.

You may need to add Firewall rule during build/release, refer to this thread: [Allow VSTS to update test database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370681/allow-vsts-to-update-test-database/43387182)

Comment: Thanks..But it does not let me execute multiple scripts sequentially

Comment: What do you mean execute multiple scripts sequentially?

Comment: we have sql scripts named as '001_XXX', '002_XXX', etc. and the requirement is to execute the sql scripts in order

Comment: How about add multiple Azure SQL Database Deployment tasks for each script files? You also can custom build/release task by calling [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) command.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to create multiple azure sql database deploy tasks..i was able to get the batch script running in CD pipeline.it executes the SQL scripts in order against Azure SQL database

Comment: @vigneshsrinivasan Ok, you can call Invoke-Sqlcmd command to run SQL scripts. You may need to add Firewall rule during build/release, check the update of my answer.

Comment: Sorry..was away for a couple of days..yes I was able to solve this issue..thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Batch Script task.

However, in general you should use SQL Server Data Tools to manage your database deployments.