# Azure Pipelines - Test Automation - Test data setup SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

We are currently using Azure pipelines to run automated UI and API tests on different test environments. Our tests are written in C# using visual studio, specflow and MStest

It's working well, but now i am looking to improve the test data set up before our tests are ran.

We use SQL server databases. Currently we use a 'Execute single or multiple SQL scripts' Azure Pipeline task to delete data in tables so we can reuse test data in our scripts. We currently only use DELETE FROM SQL commands. For example:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[table1]
DELETE FROM [dbo].[table2]
etc.
```

Obviously this is not a good solution as it requires maintenance each time there are db changes or new tables and columns are added. We run into foreign key constraints etc.

The application we are running tests on consists or 3 databases:

```
DB 1 = client db
DB 2 = Broker db
DB 3 = internal db
```

I was thinking a back up and restore of the test database before we run tests would be a better solution. However, I am unsure what the recommended best practice solution is?

I see Azure Pipelines has these tasks, but i was think maybe a sql/stored procedure script would be better?

Also, can anyone point me in the direction in what a SQL script would look like to do this?

Comment: Are you using some ORM framework?

Comment: @IanOF Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking a back up and restore of the test database before we
> run tests would be a better solution

You can follow below script to backup Azure SQL database in powershell task .

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
   -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
   -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password

$importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
[Console]::Write("Exporting")
while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
{
    $importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
    [Console]::Write(".")
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}
[Console]::WriteLine("")
$importStatus
```

For details, please refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449783/backup-azure-sql-db-during-vsts-release).