# VSTS online automated build no agent could be found

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-pipelines

For a manual build on vsts online deploying to azure things work fine.
But when I trigger from my repo, the same build, I get this:

"No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, sqlpackage"

If I go to my Build def->General Tab

[image]

Comment: are you using the same agents?

Comment: I should be, it's a little different between pressing build on on the vsts online website and having it triggered with a git repo checkin

Comment: Yeah, seems like it works fine without the sqlpackage (I removed the database project) - when it's triggered.  It did work 1 time, but most times it fails.  I bet it's a bug with their new Hosted VS2017 servers.

Comment: Maybe I can add a capability in ../_admin/_AgentQueue?


System capabilities
Shows information about the capabilities provided by this host


But I'd need a name and a value for that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So that almost worked:
When I added 

sqlpackage | C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe


I get the following error:  
Unable to find the location of Dac Framework (SqlPackage.exe) from registry on machine TASKAGENT9-0002

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the SqlPackage capability in Hosted VS2017 agent. I submit a user voice here: [VSTS SQL Package deploy with Hosted VS2017 agent](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19025347-vsts-sql-package-deploy-with-hosted-vs2017-agent).

The workaround is that you can deploy sql package to azure through PowerShell.

```
param(
    [string]$publish_profile,
    [string]$path_to_snapshots,
    [string]$database
)
$psPath=$PSScriptRoot 
write-output $psPath
Add-Type -Path "$psPath\lib\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$dacProfile = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile]::Load($publish_profile)
$dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($dacProfile.TargetConnectionString)

$files = Get-ChildItem  "$path_to_snapshots\*.dacpac"
Write-Output $path_to_snapshots
Write-Output $files.Length
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $fileName = $file.Name 
    Try
    {
        Write-output $fileName
            $dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($file.FullName)
            $dacService.Deploy($dp, $database, $true) 
           Start-Sleep -s 300
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "$fileName deployment has been failed"  -foregroundcolor "red"
         $Error | format-list -force
        Write-Host $Error[0].Exception.ParentContainsErrorRecordException;
        Break
    }
}
```

Related thread: [Deploy Dacpac packages via power shell script to Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499407/deploy-dacpac-packages-via-power-shell-script-to-azure-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I added a copy of this Microsoft script to my pipeline which returns the path to SQLPackage.exe on the agent.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/FindSqlPackagePath.ps1

At time of writing the returned path is:

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe*

If at any points the location changes in theory it should just be a case of updating it to the new location reported by the Script.