# SQL Deployment with ARM Templates including schema and table (dacpac, PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-server

I want to deploy a Azure SQL Database with schema and table using PowerShell, Azure Resource Manager Templates and dacpac. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prerequisites

- Azure Subscription
- Visual Studio with the workloads `Azure-Development` and `Datastorage- and processing` installed
- An Azure Key Vault available

### Create dacpac package with the table

- Create a new `SQL Server Database` Project
- Add a new solution folder
- Add a new schema and table SQL script
- Adjust the target platform to `Microsoft Azure SQL Platform V12` if necessary [2]
- Then build the solution -> this will create the dacpac package that can be used for the deployment (see `.\bin\debug\xxx.dacpac`)

### Deploy SQL Server with database

- Create a new `Azure Resource Group` project
- Modify the parameter and template file

  - During the deployment a firewall rule is set to allow the deployment of the dacpac. Adjust the IP address accordingly respectively when working with VSTS follow the instructions here [1]
- Then the server, database, schema and table can be deployed to Azure

### To consider

- For being able to use the dacpac package it was necessary to get the DLLs from the following source:

  - [NuGet Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/)
- When having issues while deploying the DACPAC package

  - Check firewall settings of the Azure SQL DB
  - Sometimes PowerShell seems to cache old values without overwriting them with new assigned values. When having a file not found error and you can't find the error try to restart the PowerShell environment

## Resources

[1] [Deploy Dacpac packages via power shell script to Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499407/deploy-dacpac-packages-via-power-shell-script-to-azure-sql-server)

[2] [How to: Change Target Platform and Publish a Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272687(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: did you actually include your database project within the templates? Or are you just separately deploying the dacpac package with a PS script?